# Remove text that's between last square brackets in a string (but not any other)

Tags: php, regex

So I have a complicated question that will require an advanced regular expression, which I am trying to write in PHP. I don't have a code snippet, because I really have no idea where to start with this regular expression.

I need to remove some parts of a string, ONLY if that string ends with something like [ABC].

If it starts with [ABC] or if [ABC] is somewhere in the middle, that's fine.

All I need to do is remove the [ABC] if it's at the end of the string. Problem is: the ABC can be any letter/number combination of up to 5 characters.

Some examples:

`Hello [ABC]` should become `Hello`

`[ABC] Hello` should stay `[ABC] Hello`

`[A] Hi [B]` should become `[A] Hi`

`[X] Hello [Y] World [Z]` should become `[X] Hello [Y] World`

I managed to remove all content in square brackets (including the brackets), but I have no clue how to make it only remove content + brackets if these brackets are at the very end of the string.

```
$text= "[X] Hello [Y] World [Z]";
$outputs .= preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $text);
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a site where you can ask for free work. We _need_ to see that you have made an effort, otherwise word would quickly get out that people will small programming tasks can just outsource them for free (arguably we have met that problem already, but we don't want it to get worse).

Comment: I'm fully aware of this halfer, which is why I stated in my post that I have absolutely no clue where to start. I know how to remove contents between square brackets, but I don't know how to get it to only remove this content (including the brackets) if it's at the end of a string.

Comment: If you can make a _start_ on this, that is often sufficient. You'll probably need the end anchor, which is `$`. You can test [your regex here](https://regex101.com/). The square brackets will need escaping, so that would be `\[\]`.

Comment: Useful [info about anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: Use `'/\[[^][]*\]$/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$` anchor with a negated character class instead of lazy dot matching pattern will do the job.

```
\[[^][]*]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ugxfud/1). This seems a bit more generic expression than what you need. You may adjust it for your special case - *the ABC can be any letter/number combination of up to 5 characters* - as follows:

```
\[[[:alnum:]]{1,5}]$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ugxfud/2).

**Pattern details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^][]*` - any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`

  **OR**
- `[[:alnum:]]{1,5}` - 1 to 5 alphanumeric chars
- `]` - a literal `]`
- `$`  - end of string

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/NvXEYe):

```
$text= "[X] Hello [Y] World [Z]";
$outputs = preg_replace('/\[[[:alnum:]]{1,5}]$/', '', $text);
echo trim($outputs);
// => [X] Hello [Y] World
```

Comment: `[[:alnum:]]` can be replaced with `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `[\p{L}\p{N}]`. It also depends on whether Unicode letters/digits you want to match.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for!